# SharePoint setup best practices with ISA

Tags: sharepoint, architecture, implementation

Can anyone guide me on the best way to implement SharePoint with ISA? I'm interested in setting up a basic SharePoint farm. I have tried numerous times with mixed results and I am still not sure of the best way to go.

When it is initially set up you are prompted to create a web app, but then when you go to create the ssp admin site it warns you that you're creating this in the same web app as the my sites. Is this a problem? Should I have different web apps for the content, the ssp admin site and the my sites?

I guess what I really want to know is what is the best way to set this up so it won't fall apart later once users start filling it up with everything. What are somehings to consider?

I also have a question about ISA. I've gotten SharePoint to work behind ISA but I don't think I'm doing it right. Can someone give me guidance on some considerations or best practices for accomplishing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should have seperate sites for SSP, MySites and your content.  Not a good idea to share these.

Unfortunatly there is no simple answer to your question.  Start here with the governance plan document.  It will get you going in the right direction and help you ask the right questions.  It feels like you are going down a path that will lead to "Do Not Do It This Way" lessons learned (I've been down that path).

http://blogs.msdn.com/joelo/attachment/715068.ashx

Comment: Yes, I've been there a few times actually. Thanks for the link.